# How do I find out what resolutions my graphics card supports? (AMD HD7750)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I am currently running an AMD HD7750 triple head graphics and I am thinking of upgrading one monitor to a 4K screen.

Is there a way that I can determine the maximum resolution (or combinations of resolutions) that each interface on the graphics card can support?

(Note, this isn't for gaming... .3D performance isn't of concern)

Finding the details of the card is easy enough:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for damien: 
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750 / R7 250E]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:52 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fde80000-fdebffff ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fde00000-fde1ffff
```

As is finding one details vis lspci:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750 / R7 250E] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device e213
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 4 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 52
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 2: Memory at fde80000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Region 4: I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fde00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x16, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee3f00c  Data: 4192
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [270 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: I think resolution is concerned with Screen not with graphics card.

Answer (score 3):

After researching this, I can't find any terminal command that would display the maximum resolution supported by the graphics card.

The easiest way to find out is to go to the manufacturer's website. As listed [here](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/7000/7700#), under specs, an AMD Radeon HD 7750 graphics card supports a max resolution of `4096x2160 @ 60 Hz per display`, so you should be able to upgrade to a 4k monitor. Hope this helps!

Comment: Would an implementation of either a card or a driver artificially limit these?

Comment: @Damien It's definitely possible, by altering settings, to render at a resolution lower than the monitor's resolution. Not sure if there are any settings that would outright limit/prevent the graphics card from displaying to a monitor that it would support though.

Comment: I have `Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0106] (rev 09)`. It seems that the basis is the `8086` processor. On [intel](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000023781/graphics.html) with `hdmi`(1920x1080) the resolution and hz is lower than with VGA(2048x1536, 75 Hz). I ask myself why there is a resolution diff regarding digital and analogue.

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, want to find out other compatible resolutions (lower that max) you can keep left shift pressed during boot and when GRUB shows up press the `c` key for command line.

At the `grub >` prompt enter command: `videoinfo` and it will show you a set of video resolutions compatible with your graphics card. Mainly to use when not in an graphical environment though.